# Azure Logic App FTP Copy File gives BadGateway

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-logic-apps, bad-gateway

I have a Logic App that triggers when a Blob is added or modified. The next action is to Copy file to FTP.  This only works when we edit the FTP connection and delete the port. When this runs manually it works fine.

[image]

After a few minutes, the API Connection seems to revert back to port 21.  When this happens, the Logic App fails on the FTP action with a "BadGateway" error.
[image]

The error message is:

> An FTP protocol violation was detected. This could be caused by an
>   implicit TLS/SSL configuration of the FTP server that is not
>   supported. Please try explicit TLS/SSL.

When I go back to review the FTP API Connection, the Port is set to 21.  Clearing it and rerunning the Logic App succeeds.  I have tried port 990 explicitly but that also gives a BadGateway.

[image]

Why would the Azure Logic App reset to port 21 and what can I do permanently fix this?

Comment: have you tried to delete the api conenction and recreate one ? also port 20 and 21 are dfault port for ftp

Comment: Thanks @Thomas I have deleted and created a new one, same thing.  It works momentarily then resets something behind the scenes that breaks it.  I will try port 20.

Comment: @Thomas port 20 for our FTP server must be blocked or not configured, this produced at differenge (504) GatewayTimeout